# Array sort menu

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

I have the following array to show menu's based on the order the user specified.

The array is as follows:

```
$menuArray = [
    'Main Street' => [
        ['/index.php', 'Home'],
        ['/city.php', $cityData[$user->city][0]],
        ['/travel.php', 'Travel'],
        ['/bank.php', 'Bank'],
        ['/inventory.php', 'Inventory'],
        ['/dailies.php', 'Dailies'],
    ],
    'Activities' => [
        (!$my->hospital) ? ['/hospital.php', 'Hospital'] : [],
        (!$my->hospital && !$my->prison) ? ['/crime.php', 'Crime'] : [],
        ['/missions.php', 'Missions'],
        ['/achievements.php', 'Achievements'],
    ],
    'Services' => [
        ['/hospital.php', 'Hospital'],
        ['/prison.php', 'Prison'],
        ['/search.php', 'Search'],
    ],
    'Account' => [
        ['/edit_account.php', 'Edit Account'],
        ['/notepad.php', 'Notepad'],
        ['/logout.php', 'Logout'],
    ]
];
```

I have a column `menu_order` stored in the database, which has a default value of `0,1,2,3,4`, but this can change per user as they will be able to change their menu to their likes.

What I'd like to achieve:

```
0 => Main Street
1 => Activities
2 => Services
3 => Account
4 => Communication
```

To get the menu order, I do

```
$menuOrder = explode(',', $user->menu_order);
```

But I'm not sure how to handle the foreach for displaying the menu.

Comment: your $menuArray  uses string keys, those should be returned from the db, there is no mapped relationship between the 2 here

Comment: @IdontDownVote, I could change them to integers, and handle the menu category naming in the foreach i assume?

Comment: you have an array relationship, it just has to be mapped out somewhere then you loop the sort array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this to produce the menu:

```
function display_menu($menus, $m) {
    if (!isset($menus[$m])) return;
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($menus[$m] as $item) {
        if (!count($item)) continue;
        echo "<li><a href=\"{$item[0]}\">{$item[1]}</a>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
$menuMap = array(0 => 'Main Street',
1 => 'Activities',
2 => 'Services',
3 => 'Account',
4 => 'Communication');
$menuOrder = explode(',', $user->menu_order);
foreach ($menuOrder as $menuIndex) {
    $thisMenu = $menuMap[$menuIndex];
    display_menu($menuArray, $thisMenu);
}
```

[Small demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ZEKFe)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it -- use replacement rather than a sorting algorithm.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rkOGY))

```
$menuArray = [
    'Main Street' => [],
    'Activities' => [],
    'Services' => [],
    'Account' => []
];
$lookup = [
    0 => 'Main Street',
    1 => 'Activities',
    2 => 'Services',
    3 => 'Account',
    4 => 'Communication'
];

$customsort = '4,2,1,3,0';

$keys = array_flip(explode(',', $customsort));  convert string to keyed array
//var_export($keys);

$ordered_keys = array_flip(array_replace($keys, $lookup));  // apply $lookup values to keys, then invert key-value relationship
//var_export($ordered_keys);

$filtered_keys = array_intersect_key($ordered_keys, $menuArray);  // remove items not on the current menu ('Communication" in this case)
//var_export($filtered_keys);

$final = array_replace($filtered_keys, $menuArray);  // apply menu data to ordered&filtered keys
var_export($final);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Services' => 
  array (
  ),
  'Activities' => 
  array (
  ),
  'Account' => 
  array (
  ),
  'Main Street' => 
  array (
  ),
)
```

---

And here's another way using `uksort()` and a spaceship operator:

```
$ordered_keys = array_flip(array_values(array_replace(array_flip(explode(',', $customsort)), $lookup)));

uksort($menuArray, function($a, $b) use ($ordered_keys) {
    return $ordered_keys[$a] <=> $ordered_keys[$b];
});
var_export($menuArray);
```

As a consequence of how your are storing your custom sort order, most of the code involved is merely to set up the "map"/"lookup" data.